# Error NullPointerException al intentar conectarme a la base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

Tengo un problema al conectarme al gestor de mi base de datos, aparece el error:

> "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Cuando envío un objeto a la clase que los interpreta y guarda en una base de datos **MYSQL**.

Lo que hace este código es crear un objeto `Campeonato` a base de los campos que se encuentran en la ventana, el objeto se crea correctamente **(ya que lo muestro en un syso)**, sin embargo al intentar guardarlo con el `preparedStatement` no se guarda de ninguna manera.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at basesDeDatos.GestorBD.gJuez(GestorBD.java:142)
    at campeonato.VentanaSignIn$2.actionPerformed(VentanaSignIn.java:436)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

Este es el código del gestor:

```
    //GUARDAR CAMPEONATO
    public void gCrearCampeonato(Campeonato c) throws BDexception {
        try {
          pStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO campeonato VALUES (default, ?, ?, ?, null, ?, null, ?)");

          pStatement.setString(1, c.getNombre());
          pStatement.setString(2, c.getLugar());
          pStatement.setString(3, c.getF_inicio());
          pStatement.setString(4, c.getPatr_princ());
          pStatement.setInt(5, c.getCoste());

          pStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new BDexception("Error al crear el campeonato", e);
        }
    }

-- -
```

Esta es la parte de código que llama al `gCrearCampeonato`:

```
protected Connection conn = null;z
btnCrearCampeonato.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
            Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
            String nombre = txtNombreCamp.toString();
            String lugar = txtLugar.toString();
            String f_inicio = df.format(calobj.getTime());
            String f_fin = null;
            String patr_princ = comboPatrocinador.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int coste = Integer.parseInt(txtCoste.getText());
            int recaudacion = 0;
            int ganancia = 0;
            Manga[] mangas = null;

            Campeonato c = new Campeonato(nombre, lugar, f_inicio, f_fin, patr_princ, coste, recaudacion, ganancia, mangas);
            System.out.println("patata");

            try {
                gestor.gCrearCampeonato(c);
            } catch (BDexception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Normalmente ese error es causado cuando invocas una referencia a objeto que no ha sido creada.  En tu código por ejemplo, no he encontrado la creación del objeto apuntado por la referencia "conn".

Comment: Ese no es el problema, he añadido el trozo de código donde lo declaro. El hecho es que enviado desde una clase me funciona pero desde esta en concreto no.